# Why does tr command allow unexpected characters?

Tags: unix, tr

I'm running on OMVS environment.

In the following command I had not expected to see an output with any NON alphanumeric characters.

```
echo $(head /dev/urandom | tr -cd '[:alnum:]' | head -c 32)
```

However an example of what I see in output is:

```
J0SPNN-b0PZwbwHzeMAqIE0ufKJdnNJb
```

I have realized the shown dash ('-') is merely a graphical representation, but in reality different hex values all show like this. I have so far seen values between x'30' and x'3E', but expected the tr -cd '[:alnum:]' to only pass on a-zA-Z0-9, so where do these other values come from?

Answer (score 0):

If I run your command on my Mac I get "tr: Illegal byte sequence" and the way I can get it to work is:

```
head /dev/urandom | LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd '[:alnum:]' | head -c 32
```

(You don't need the surrounding `echo` statement.)

That is, telling it to use the input as a "C-string" rather than interpret it as UTF8.

I don't have a spare mainframe to test, but I suspect the answer is along the same lines.